# Как получить Array[Byte], не сохраняя результат в файл?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Надо сохранить отчет в csv формате, сжатый Gzip. Делается это очень просто:

```scala
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save(s"result.csv.gz")
```

Теперь усложнение: сохранить надо на "Яндекс.Диск", для этого мне надо получить `encodedDf: Array[Byte]`.

Как это можно красивее оформить?

Comment: Я конечно довольно быстро сообразил сделать `write.repartition(1)`, сохранить всё в один временный файл, прочитать из него `Array[Byte]`, отправить по месту назначения и удалить временный файл. 

Только выглядит это всё каким-то извращением)

Вопрос именно в красивом решении, без подобных костылей

Comment: Как вариант, можно получить строки и использовать обычную CSV-библиотеку и обычную библиотеку для сжатия. Попробуйте еще `writeStream` вместо `write`, а затем `.foreach(ForeachWriter)`